# Divisi in Tchaikovsky Serenade for Strings

Tags: notation, strings, violin, musescore

I am looking at the score for Tchaikovsky's Serenade for Strings op.48, Violins I section, and I can see that there are double-stops. It is not marked divisi, but I'm listening to some recordings and live performances and I don't think that they are being played, i.e. it appears that they are playing divisi.

What would be the correct/implied way to play this?

Answer (score 6):

From reviewing the score and a video, it seems clear that Tchaikovsky intended the parts to be played as double stops but most orchestras seem to be dividing it up.

There is a section of clearly marked divisi in the second violins not long after the intro is over. That means that anything not marked divisi is intentionally so.

That said, it doesn’t look (or sound) like it’s being played as double stops in the videos I saw. Conductors can and do take liberties with works, so that could be what we are seeing here.

My guess is that it’s easier to render it sweetly and lyrically by playing it divisi. I’m sure pros can do effective double stop vibrato but to my ears double stops seem a bit more aggressive than the same notes played divisi. That only leaves the question of whether Tchaikovsky wanted it to sound so sweet or not.

Comment: Yes it is certainly a lot easier to play sweetly and lyrically by playing it divisi. It is just that the score says "sempre marcatissimo", and that could be underlined by playing it non-divisi. But that makes it a lot harder to make a good intonation.

Comment: I've been in performances that specifically agreed to play it non divisi (and others where individuals simply did it to show off)